# Show an equilibrium $x=0$ is asymptotically stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Merry Xmas everyone! Hope you all had a great day:)

I'm currently getting stuck on the following problem, due to the inability to use one of a key hypothesis given. Here is the problem:

Given the system $\dot{x} = Ax + h(x)$ in $R^{n}$ where $A =  n\times n$ matrix such that all the eigenvalues of $A$ have real part $< 0$, and $h : R^n\rightarrow R^n$ satisfies $h(0) = 0$ and $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ \frac{|h(x)|}{|x|} = 0$ (this condition is equivalent to $h'(0) = 0$). Prove that the equilibrium $x = 0$ is asymptotically stable.

**My question:** I can't see how the condition $h'(0) = 0$ comes into play. My idea is to use Variation of Parameters formula, but that formula doesn't have anything to do with $h'(0) = 0$. Can somebody please help me with the proof, or at least a new approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about using Variation of parameters. The proof is quite elaborate and uses [Gronwall's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality). Here is a [link](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/hhu/848/lec_17.pdf) to a PDF which contains this result. You should be looking at Theorem 15.3.

Disclaimer: All credit is due to the original author of this article.

Comment: @user177196 let me know if you have questions concerning the proof.

Comment: fantastic link! A hard, but beautiful, proof:)

Comment: @user177196 I'm glad you like it! It is quite interesting :)